# AngularJS Spring MVC setup

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am a beginner for Spring MVC.
I want to use AngularJS and Spring MVC to setup a RESTful Single Page Application.

As a normal web app, when user request a URI, the backend web server will first transfer HTML template
to front end and then use JSON to communicate.

I just wonder how HTML template are transferred to front end from Spring MVC service.

Any information will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, and imho more sutiable to your requirements don't bother with the initial controller, and just serve your html and javascript as static resources , using something like this in your spring conf :

```
<mvc:resources location="/app/" mapping="/app/**"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

And then only interact with backend using ajax and rest controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NimChimpsky, need to add tag <mvc:annotation-driven/> as well.

Comment: I got another question, After I edit index.html page, I must restart web server to get the update. Is there any way that I can just refresh web page to get the update? Thanks a lot for any information.

Comment: you shouldn;t need to d that, if you set up your dev envirnometn correctly. Ar eyou sure the browser is not caching the page ?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared browser caching, but it still not worked.Can you help to see the question I asked for this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361173/spring-mvc-static-contents-auto-reload-issue

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I have problem exactly with initial controller, I can't get rid of it. Solution is `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/resources/index.html"/>`, but still it is a by-pass. Would you like to look at my question if you can? Thank you in advance for help. Here it is: [Get rid of first View Controller with Spring 4 and AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479850/get-rid-of-first-view-controller-with-spring-4-and-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example (taken from the Spring Guide [Consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/)) is the following:

Create an html page that is accessible statically (using Spring Boot as is done in the guide means that there a few standard places that will automatically be used for static resourses - if you don't use Spring Boot you will have to configure this), like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{greeting.message}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `hello.js` script could be

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://yourpath/greeting').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
}
```

And then the corresponding Spring Service would be:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

   @RequestMapping("/greeting")
   public Greeting greeting() {
      return new Greeting();
   }

}

public class Greeting {
   private final Integer id;
   private final String message;

   public Greeting() {
      this(1,"test")
   }

   public Greeting(Integer id, String message) {
      this.id = id;
      this.message = message;
   }

   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public String getMessage() {
      return message;
   }
}
```

In this very simple example, the template was transfered to the front-end simply because it was accessible as a static resource.
You could of course imagine a more complex scenario where the controller would be something like

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

   @RequestMapping("/greeting")
   public ModelAndView greeting() {
      return new ModelAndView("someView", someObject);
   }

}
```

and Spring MVC would map `someView` to a template based on the configured `ViewResolver`.
That way the template is dynamically populated by the server with whatever data is needed.

You can take a look at some more tutorials:

- [Developing Single Page Applications with Spring, MongoDB, and AngularJS](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-22-developing-single-page-applications-with-spring-mongodb-and-angularjs)
- [Complete Web Application: Angular Twitter Bootstrap Spring MVC, Data and Security](http://uaihebert.com/complete-web-application-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-and-security/).