# Spring MVC static contents auto reload issue

Tags: html, spring, model-view-controller, jetty

Right now, I am using Spring MVC to build RESTful web service.
After web server started, index.html page are shown in browser.
But If I change the content of index.html, I must restart web service in order to see the update.(I have cleared browser cached, it's not worked either.)
Is there any way that I just need to refresh web page to get the update after I changed the content of index.html?
Do I need any configuration or code? By the way, I use Jetty as my web server.

Any information will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Below is my configuration files.

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>disableCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.springapp.mvc.setting.DisableCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>disableCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/app/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a hard refresh, ctrl-f5 in windows. And you turn off caching for websites in you browser dev tools.

To confirm it is browser caching, you simply view the static file in the server's deployed dir.

Or if you are talking about hot deployment, that is ide specific - in intellij you must start in debug mode and use an exploded war. Eclipse/netbeans can't remember how you do it, but they can.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NimChimpsky. Yes, what I mean is hot deployment. I use intellij and start in debug model with exploded war. But still not working.

Comment: in your run/debu config there is update action/on frame deactivation. Set this to update resources and classes.

Comment: Haha, It's worked. Thank you very much @NimChimpsky. Spring MVC does not support hot deployment itself. Intellij is awesome.

Comment: I have tried this out. It will work fine for just to set frame deactivation to update resources and classes, do not must start in debug mode. :)

Comment: oh does it (thats my hangover from eclipse), I normally dev in debug mode so I can set breakpoints