# Get rid of first View Controller with Spring 4 and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I use `RestController` to fetch data with `AngularJS`, but still I need *regular* controller to load `index.html`:

```
@Controller
public final class LayoutController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "/resources/index";
    }
}
```

Every other controllers are `RestController`s. If index file has `jsp` extension, I don't neeed `LayoutController`, but when it is `html` it is needed.
This is my `dispatcher` config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"></property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And this is part of `applicationContext`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Is there a way to get rid of `LayoutController` when I want to use `index.html` instead of `index.jsp`? Thank you in advance for help.
**Solution based on accepted answer:**

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/resources/index.html"/>
```

Without `LayoutController` and `InternalResourceViewResolver` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `view-controller`,

`<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>`

I am assuming you already have a InternalResourceViewResolver pointing to the jsp location . If not you also have to include it in application context.

`<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>`

if you don't wanna include InternalResourceViewResolver you can also directly forward to html.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="forward:/WEB-INF/resources/index.html"/>
```

Hope , this is what you was looking for.

Comment: Thank you :)  I got rid of need for LayoutController and InternalResourceViewResolver with directly pointing to HTML file, but for me final solution looks a little bit different than yours: `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/resources/index.html"/>` - and Intellij shows me "can not resolve symbol '/resources/index.html' ", but... It works.